# How to extract data from an array of objects to render a list in an html email template? Using React/Formik/Sendgrid

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, sendgrid

So, basically I have a form data that I am having trouble parsing correctly. I keep getting [object Object]'s in the response for the listPets variable. Every other variable is mapping correctly. Anyone have any ideas on how I could go about this? :)

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    email: '',
    password: '',
    jobType: '',
    comments: '',
    cookies: [],
    terms: '',
    newsletter: '',
    firstName: '',
    pets: [{ type: '', name: '', id: '1' }]
  }}
  validationSchema={ LoginSchema }
  onSubmit={ 
    async data => {
      await sleep(1000);
      setStatus(prevStatus => ({ ...prevStatus }));
      const res = await fetch('/api/send', { method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                  });

      const text = await res.text();
      handleResponse(res.status, text);
    }
  }
>

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

export default async function(req, res){ 
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const { email, comments, firstName, cookies, jobType, pets } = req.body;


  const content = {
    to: '',
    from: email,
    subject: `New Message From - ${email}`,
    text: comments,
    html: `
    <p>Hi, ${firstName}.</p>
    <p>${comments}</p>
    <p>${cookies}</p>
    <p>${jobType}</p>
    <p>${listPets}</p> 
    `
  };

  try {
    console.log('Content', content);
    res.status(200).send('Message sent successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR', error);
    res.status(400).send('Message not sent.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JSON.stringify(pets) to debug whats happening? I would have commented but i dont have enough reputation.

Comment: yeah, no worries any response is helpful! I'm still relatively new to the whole programming world and still trying to wrap my head around alot of this stuff. But so, when I console.log(JSON.stringify(pets)) everything  seemed to come back okay. For, example:

 Pets [{"type":"dog","name":"Timmy","id":"1"},{"type":"cat","name":"Billy","id":"6GKXXqGG"}]

Now, i'm just wondering how I can get that data into the html within the content variable.

Comment: This part seems a bit weird :

const listPets = pets.map(pet => <li key={pet.id}>{pet.name}</li>); ...You are aware its making an array of <li>, right? Instead of  <p>${listPets}</p> maybe try  <p>${listPets}.join("")</p>

Comment: const listPets = JSON.stringify(pets);

 const joinPets = listPets.join("");

  <p>${joinPets}</p>  

This is giving me listPets.join is not a function error. I dont know if I did that right exactly though. Ideally, I would like to try to get the email to create a list item for each pets object something like:

Name: ""
Type: ""

Name:""
Type:""